# How do I remove poison?

Tags: ultima-6

I know that Lord British can remove poison and heal the party but when he is sleeping what can I do? I don't remember if there is a potion or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Red potions and Dispel Magic can apparently cure poison.

If I remember correctly, you can also awaken Lord British (using Dispel Magic, Mass Awaken, or a blue potion?) in the middle of the night and then ask him for healing.

Comment: Now I remember the trick to awake Lord British, nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, "Dispel Magic" cures poison:

http://www.gameboomers.com/wtcheats/pcUu/Ultima6sh.htm